# Internet Explorer Adding Inline Styles to List

Tags: css, internet-explorer

http://philliesnation.com/

I am currently debugging this site for Internet Explorer and am running into two issues:

1. In IE7/8/9 at the bottom of each post there is a "Filed Under:" section that has a ul set at 200px wide. But for some reason in IE it is being shrunk down to 50px by adding an inline style to each li item. Therefor, the section shows up vertical instead of horizontal. In FF/Ch/Saf it looks fine.
2. In IE7 the main navigation is not properly working. If you scroll over nav points you get a dropdown with more information, but on on three tabs: News/Features/Multimedia these dropdowns dont work at all.

I did not build this site but am helping to debug it and have been trying for numerous hours on end to figure out why these bugs occur. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by resolving as many of these [W3 validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fphilliesnation.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) as possible and then work from there

Answer (score 1):

To fix your first issue: In your `func.js` you have the following line:

```
if( $.browser.msie ) {
    $('.post-links ul li').css({ 'width' : '50px' });
};
```

Thats whats messing up the width of your "File Under.." section in IE. Remove that and all is well (i see no reason why to keep it).

For your second issue: I can't quite diagnose the problem because your site keeps freezing my IE browser (it's so heavy!!) but from what i can tell your nav script is not firing in IE correctly, so you're going to have to force it with some conditional comments in the header of your document, like so:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  #navigation li:hover .dd-menu {
      display: block;
  }
<![endif]-->
```